# Output of loop appends to csv but content does not change with iteration

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

My function is iterating over chunks of a dataframe. There is one desired output from each chunk that I am trying to write into a csv file.

The code has been made, and I have checked it at every stage possible but cannot find the problem. Sorry, I am a bit of a beginner here.
When calling `print (i)` instead of the function, I can see that all different chunks are being generated, so the problem is to do with writing into the file. Here is the code

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model as sm


def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

with open("betaweights.csv", 'w') as my_csv: 
        writer = csv.writer(my_csv)
        writer.writerow(['status', 'sdstatus', 'physicalstatus', 'sd', 'physical', 'trial_sex'])

        for i in chunker(df,184):

            cols_to_keep = ['correct', 'status', 'sdstatus', 'physicalstatus', 'sd', 'physical', 'trial_sex']
            data = df[cols_to_keep] 
            data['intercept'] = 1.0

            #train and fit model
            train_cols = data.columns[1:]
            logit = sm.Logit(data['correct'], data[train_cols])
            result = logit.fit()

            #look at model output
            result_summary = result.summary()
            result_as_html = result_summary.tables[1].as_html()
            output = pd.read_html(result_as_html, header=0, index_col=0)[0]
            desired_output = output.iloc[[0,1,2,3,4,5], 0]

            writer.writerow(desired_output)
```

can anyone see what has gone wrong here? would really appreciate it -thanks. To clarify, the CSV has the correct number of new rows, but the contents are identical

EDIT: From the comments I tried pandas chunksize, so my code would look like this

```
df_chunk = pd.read_csv(path + 'logistic_regression.csv', chunksize = 184)

with open("betaweights.csv", 'w') as my_csv: 
        writer = csv.writer(my_csv)
        writer.writerow(['status', 'sdstatus', 'physicalstatus', 'sd', 'physical', 'trial_sex'])

        for chunk in df_chunk:

            #perform a regression model on the chunk and get predictor        
            #variables and beta weights as 
            #the desired output (as shown in the code above)

            desired_output = output.iloc[[0,1,2,3,4,5], 0]

            writer.writerow(desired_output)
```

Since this still doesn't work, I think am just doing something plainly wrong with the formatting of the for loop

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: Print `output` and `desired_output ` right after they are assigned a value. I am guessing they are not changing in reach iteration of the for loop. Ex: `print(output)`

Comment: At which part of your code are you using your chunks, in this case `for i in chunker..`. Also if it is in a dataframe is there a reason why you are not using the default `chunksize` parameter in `pandas`?

Comment: ```desired output``` is just a couple of values in ```output``` which has excess information

Comment: @BernardL I hadn't actually considered pandas chunk size - so thank you for that ill check it out

Comment: Can you expand on _there is one desired output from each chunk_ a bit more? The `chunksize` parameter to `read_csv` likely isn't what you're looking for here, by the way.

Comment: I'm thinking the easiest would be read entire DataFrame -> perform operations on chunks/groups, creating new DataFrame -> output entire DataFrame new to csv at once.

Comment: Do I need to have the word 'chunk' written somewhere in my loop content?

Comment: All sorted: my initial code said `data = df[cols_to_keep] ` when it should've said `data = i[cols_to_keep] `

Comment: @charlotte Great!